# How to performe deep packet inspection using Ryu controller fot Qos Perposes

Tags: python, scapy, sdn, qos, ryu

I am trying to prioritize **voice & video** traffic over other types of traffic , i am using scapy to inspect and capture the traffic , i cant find a way to distinguish between those types. the field `tos` is always `tos=0x0` .
i am doing this to send a set of rules to **SDN** edges using **Ryu Controller**

Comment: If you haven't changed the ToS value, then when you read traffic with it, it also won't be changed.

Comment: Also, please don't ask the same question twice. You've already asked it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61491979/how-to-inspect-voice-video-traffic-flows-in-a-sdn-ruy-controller).

Comment: i deleted the other questions sir , 
yes that's the point , i will not be asking the endpoints to change there Tos this isn't possible in the real world , that's why i am looking for an other way to differentiate traffic , DPI could help but how ?

Comment: How should scapy differentiate between ToS values that are all the same?

Comment: it couldn't  , i should find an other way